# MySQL Query Failed: Expression #6 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains non aggregated column fixed bug reappear every restart

Tags: mysql, php, greatest-n-per-group

```
MySQL Query Failed: Expression #6 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
```

This bug is fixed using below query. by logging into MySQL console as root user

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

But the problem is that this bug reappears every time i restarts the system.
How to fix this?

Comment: @Akina can you tell me an example for partial MySQL queries?

Comment: @Akina thank you also please make an answer for this question so that i can accept the same

Comment: Done. Comments are deleted and moved to the answer.

Comment: That's not a bug - it's the correct way to handle GROUP BY statements.

Comment: You upgraded MySQL recently?

Comment: @RickJames No, My version is this MySQL 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a bug. That's 'move to standard'.

Do not fix this problem by change server's SQL Mode. Fix it by altering the queries which uses partial `GROUP BY` expressions.

Details can be read in [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Answer (score 3):

You should add it to your config file, for example: /etc/my.cnf:

```
sql_mode='...'
```

Do note that this is not a bug, this is the way it is supposed to work. By disabling this check you risk getting indeterministic answers from your queries. A small example:

```
create table t (x int not null, y int not null, z int not null);
insert into t (x,y,z) values (1,1,2),(1,2,3);
```

What would be the result of:

```
select x,y,max(z) from t group by x
```

? MAX(z) in the group x is 3. What value should y have, 1 or 2? This would be logically valid if y were functionally dependent on x, but in this case, there is neither a constraint that guarantees it nor data that conforms to it.

Comment: This also an answer but the right answer is which I have accepted above. But, I am using this solution time being.